# Looping flv without flicker

Tags: flash, loops, flv

I'm looking for a way to loop a flv file seamlessly in Flash CS6. When I use the code below the video disappears for a fraction of a second before replaying, which isn't pretty at all.

This is the code I used:

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
flvFile.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoFinished);
 function videoFinished(event:Event){
         flvFile.play();
 };
```

Now, please bear with me, I'm really inexperienced in Flash. As a matter of fact, I've only started using it as of today. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193937/how-to-loop-flv-seamlessly

Comment: I used the following code now, but the flv doesn't even apear when I view the swf in my browser:

`ManOpBank.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
  function onStatus(item:Object):void {
    if (item.info.code == "ManOpBank.Buffer.Empty") {
        if (loop) ManOpBank.seek(0);
    }
  }`

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way :P take a screenshot of the first frame and place it behind your flv ;p then when it disappears for a fraction of a second you'll see the first frame :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Flash Player 11.x and AIR 3.x: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3349340 - some workarounds in response to this question: [How to loop FLV seamlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193937/how-to-loop-flv-seamlessly/19578094#19578094)